# Poland 80th anniversary of WW2. How many international leaders rejected personal visit?

Tags: european-union, europe, poland, world-war-ii

As known, Poland recently marks 80th anniversary of WW2 start:
https://www.reuters.com/article/us-ww2-anniversary-poland/poland-marks-80th-anniversary-of-start-of-world-war-two-idUSKCN1VL0TL

Also, I've heard, that very many (mostly)western leaders were invited to the ceremony:
https://www.thefirstnews.com/article/polish-president-invites-world-leaders-to-wwii-outbreak-anniversary-5149

But on the video I can see only Steinmeier from the valuable western leaders.

How many western leaders rejected personal visit to Poland?
(I've heard about D.Trump and hurricane, but what about the others?)

Comment: Suddenly, a downvote.. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Pakistani news site [urdupoint](https://www.urdupoint.com/en/world/twenty-heads-of-state-to-visit-poland-for-80t-697268.html) writes that about twenty heads of state are expected, but I haven't seen any list or group photo yet.

Attendees:

- Angela Merkel (Germany)
- Volodymyr Zelensky (Ukraine)
- Janos Ader (Hungary)
- Borut Pahor (Slovenia)
- Edouard Philippe (France)
- Charles Michel (Belgium)
- (probably) Guðni Th. Jóhannesson (Iceland)

Absentees:

- Vladimir Putin (Russia; not invited)
- Donald Trump (USA; cancelled visit due to hurricane)

  - Present: Vice President Mike Pence,
- Boris Johnson (UK; just called new elections)

  - Present: London mayor Sadiq Khan
- Aleksandar Vučić (Serbia, not invited)

Sources:

- [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7416009/London-mayor-Sadiq-Khan-joins-poignant-service-marking-80th-anniversary-WWII.html)
- [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/powerpost/pence-praises-courage-of-polish-people-on-80th-anniversary-of-start-of-world-war-ii/2019/09/01/6231b89e-ccc1-11e9-8c1c-7c8ee785b855_story.html?noredirect=on)
- [Iceland Review](https://www.icelandreview.com/news/icelandic-president-visits-poland-for-wwii-commemoration/)
- [RT France](https://francais.rt.com/international/65457-exclue-commemorations-guerre-pologne-russie-rappelle-urss-vaincu-nazisme)

Comment: Fast like a lightning.. But some remarks. Were Merkel really there? Haven't spotted her.. Or was it originally invited and send Steinmeier instead?

Comment: Suddenly read recently: "leaders of all countries within NATO, the European Union and the EU's Eastern Partnership (Armenia, Azerbaijan, Moldova, Ukraine, Georgia and Belarus),". Seems, that most states have rejected. Added this link to the question

Comment: @user2501323: It seems that Merkel is present at the official ceremony. I don't know, if Steinmeier is still there. It seems that he has another official event on weekend, but I doubt that both Germany's President and Chancellor would attend the same event. (The US President and the Vice President would never appear together for security reasons.)

Comment: I see. Yeah, that's strange - I'm also sure they aren't both there.

Comment: " but I doubt that both Germany's President and Chancellor would attend the same event. (The US President and the Vice President would never appear together for security reasons.) " The president is only ceremonial, so the considerations that arise in the US don't arise in germany. the more concerning thing is chancellor and vice chancellor, but they have travelled together as well.

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt, regarding security one should remember that the SecDef and not the Chancellor is the peacetime commander-in-chief, and that the Chanellor's deputy is the Vice Chancellor while the President's "designated successor" is the President of the Parliament. I've seen no pics but news reports state that **both** were in Poland.

Comment: @o.m.: I'm  aware that the situation is not comparable. Still, I doubt that security like it, when head of state and head of government are together at public events. I'm curious, if there will be any photo with both of them.